# In Fedora, Perl program cannot find Time::Piece library

Tags: linux, time, perl, fedora-17

I have a Perl program named `/usr/bin/octbatch` running as a script on Fedora 17 Linux.

When I run this command:

```
/usr/bin/octbatch
```

I get the error:

```
Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at /usr/bin/octbatch line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/octbatch line 6.
```

Here is the relevant lines of the Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

$ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin";
use strict;
use POSIX qw(setsid :sys_wait_h);

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Local;
```

I have to install Piece.pm so perl can find it.  I've already installed it with this command (using the defaults):

```
/usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e install Time::Piece
```

I have the Piece.pm file in `/home/el/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/` however when I run the octbatch command I get the same error as above.  Like it can't even find it.

Here is my PERL5LIB variable:

```
el@defiant ~/gnuoctbluehost/single_stock_analysis $ env | grep PERL5

PERL5LIB=/home/el/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi:/home/el/perl5/lib/perl5
```

And the Piece.pm is located under /home/el/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi

So my question is, Why is it not finding my Piece.pm file?  And what are the ways I can get the @INC variable to include it.  Or how do I make perl see it?

Answer (score 2):

**Fedora 17 include Time::Piece**

Use the command: `yum install perl-Time-Piece`

You can find that out with google search: `fedora 17 Time-Piece` and hit the first link.

**Work around to manually include the path and library:**

Make sure the following line is before `use Time::Piece;` but after `#!/usr/bin/perl -wT`.

```
use lib "/home/el/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi";
```

Which tells my perl program where to look for Time::Piece.  Then the program works.